# Wordpress Plugin executes SQL multiple times

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

I created a simple Wordpress Plugin which stores Text-Data in database

```
if(isset($_POST['staticbox_submit'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE staticbox SET content = '".$_POST['staticbox_content']."';";
    if(!$wpdb->query($sql)) {echo '<p style="color:#990000;">Fehlgeschlagen.</p>';} else {echo '<p style="color:#009900;">Ausgef&uuml;hrt.</p>';}   
}
```

and outputs it in the frontend

```
function staticbox() {
    global $wpdb;

    $staticbox_content = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT content FROM staticbox" );
    foreach($staticbox_content as $item) {echo $item;}
}
```

I have a textarea and button within a form. If the post-variable of the button is set it stores the text in database.

```
    <form action="?page=staticbox/main.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="staticbox_content" cols="100" rows="10"><?php $staticbox_content = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT content FROM staticbox" );   foreach($staticbox_content as $item) {echo $item;} ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" name="staticbox_submit" />
    </form>
```

For any reason the text is stored 3 times in database. Can you help me find the problem?

### Here are some screenshots

**What I entered in Backend**

[image: What I entered in Backend]

**What it looks like in MySQL**

[image]

**What it looks like in Frontend**

[image: What it looks like in Frontend]

**EDIT:**
Heres the whole file:

```
<?php
/*** WIRD BEIM AKTIVIEREN AUSGEFÜHRT ***/
function staticbox_activate() {
    $sql = "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staticbox` (
        `content` text NOT NULL 
        )";
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'staticbox_activate' );

/*** WIRD BEIM DEINSTALLIEREN AUSGEFÜHRT ***/
function staticbox_uninstall() {
    $sql = "DROP TABLE `staticbox`";
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'staticbox_uninstall' );

/*** DIE FRONTEND FUNKTIONEN ***/
function staticbox() {
    global $wpdb;

    $staticbox_text = "<strong>Überschrift</strong><p>Der Text wurde hier eingefügt</p>";
    $staticbox_text_html = utf8_encode($staticbox_text);
    $staticbox_content = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT content FROM staticbox" );
    foreach($staticbox_content as $item) {echo $item;}
}

/*** DIE BACKEND FUNKTIONEN ***/
function staticbox_admin() {
    global $wpdb;   ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Staticbox</h2>
        <p>Hier k&ouml;nnen Sie der Staticbox Inhalt geben, welcher dann im Frontend ausgegeben wird.</p>
        <p>Dies erfolgt durch das Einspeisen folgender Funktion an einer beliebigen Stelle im Theme des Blogs:</p>
        <code>
            if ( function_exists ( staticbox() ) ) {
                staticbox();
            }
        </code>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <h3>Inhalt einf&uuml;gen</h3>
        <form action="?page=staticbox/main.php" method="post">
            <textarea name="staticbox_content" cols="100" rows="10"><?php $staticbox_content = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT content FROM staticbox" );   foreach($staticbox_content as $item) {echo $item;} ?></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" name="staticbox_submit" />
        </form>
        <?php echo $_POST['staticbox_content']; ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['staticbox_submit'])) {
        $sql = "UPDATE staticbox SET content = '".$_POST['staticbox_content']."';";
        if(!$wpdb->query($sql)) {echo '<p style="color:#990000;">Fehlgeschlagen.</p>';} else {echo '<p style="color:#009900;">Ausgef&uuml;hrt.</p>';}   
    }

    echo $sql;
}

/*** DIE MENÜS WERDEN HINZUGEFÜGT ***/
function staticbox_menu() {
  add_menu_page('Staticbox', 'Staticbox', 10, __FILE__, 'staticbox_admin');
  //add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Bloggerei', 'Bloggerei', 10, 'bloggerei', 'bloggerei');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'staticbox_menu');

?>
```

Comment: The problem is in the first block of code. Can you show more of it? Is that a `save_post` action? Also, your code is insecure, check [`wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Comment: Not sure about your particular problem, but your code is not safe from sql injection (just in case you haven't trimmed it down for brevity).

Comment: Your plugin is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: That textarea is only visible in backend.How can someone inject SQL into it?
EDIT: Nevermind I guess via Post.

Comment: @brasofilo I edited so you can see.

Comment: Just want to clarify before posting an answer - every time you submit the textarea data, do you get 3 more entries in your table? (3 more rows - or do the same 3 rows stick around with updated data)?

Comment: @Ryven no, I dont get 3 more tables. It simply updates the table with 3x the new text.

Comment: Ok now I solved that problem by renaming the file to what the folder is called. I saw that other plugins have one file named what the plugin is named in their main directory but I didnt know it was essential.

Comment: Have you done something about the SQL-Injection?